# How to add RGB png picture?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, png

My PIL is not able to load my png. I only get a big white screen so the code is working but i am not able to get the actual picture on the GUI.

I have tried various of ways and every time i load a black and white picture it's fine but if it has color then it won't load.

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.Image

    TkbannerImg = PIL.Image.open("icon.png")
    bannerPhoto = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(bannerImg)

    label = Label(self.master, image=bannerPhoto)
    label.image = bannerPhoto # reference
    label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    label.place(x=self.globalX / 5.45, y=self.globalY / 3.56)
```

Final result looks like this (pay attention to the input field how most of it is blocked by whitespace, that is meant to be the picture): https://i.stack.imgur.com/594Tg.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed in `PhotoImage` should be `TkbannerImg` instead of `bannerImg` 
Try this :

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.Image

    TkbannerImg = PIL.Image.open("icon.png")
    bannerPhoto = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(TkbannerImg)

    label = Label(self.master, image=bannerPhoto)
    label.image = bannerPhoto # reference
    label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    label.place(x=self.globalX / 5.45, y=self.globalY / 3.56)
```